# React Native StyleSheet.create exception

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

so I am creating these styles and passing on this view. I am importing the right way... i really dont understand whats the issue...

I already researched here on stackoverflow i saw something about StyleSheet.flatten but it couldnt help.

in the picture it can be clarified the problem. Its giving not to this file but every file, btw. and one of the files its giving the problem. So if any further information is required, i can edit this question providing those informations

could someone help me to understand that?

[image: Reac]

Comment: Please post relevant code block of the problem, code picture won’t help. Also to narrow down try using only one component and see what happens

Comment: You may have not imported StyleSheet from react native in another file.

Comment: SaachiTech, i will do that. Dushan Randika, i will double check but im pretty sure I imported on all files. I will check with only one file and see what i get.

Comment: I tried all of that and still same problem. I killed and restarted the server, closed and opened xcode, same thing. I ran a brand new expo and no issues were found. Then, I copied testing one file by one and i fixed the issue. Not ideal, I didnt touch any expo file, only App.js and the ones i created. Idk what was the issue, honestly.